# With a has_many relationship, in the returned collection, include? does not recognize equality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, equality

In one of my models I have defined equality to also work with strings and symbols. A role is equal to another role (or string or symbol), if its name attribute is the same:

```
class Role
  def == other
    other_name = case other
                 when Role then other.name
                 when String, Symbol then other.to_s
                 end
    name == other_name
  end
end
```

The equality checking works correct:

```
role = Role.create name: 'admin'
role == 'admin' # => true
role == :admin  # => true
```

But when I use the `Role` model in a has_many relationship, in the collection I get, `include?` does not recognized this equality:

```
user = User.create
user.roles << role
User.roles.include? role    # => true
User.roles.include? 'admin' # => false 
User.roles.include? :admin  # => false
```

In order to make this work, I have to explicitly convert this to an array:

```
User.roles.to_a.include? 'admin' # => true
User.roles.to_a.include? :admin  # => true
```

So apparently Rails overrides the `include?` method in the array returned by `user.roles`. This sucks and is contrary to rubys [specification](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F) of `Enumerable#include?` (which explicitly states, that "Equailty is tested using `==`"). This is not true for the array I get from `user.roles`. `==` is never even called.

**Where is this modified behavior of `include?` specified?**

**Is there another way to test for inclusion that I missed? Or do I have to use `to_a` or an actual instance of `Role` everytime?**

Comment: What does this: `User.roles.class` give in your console?

Comment: @grotori : user.roles.class # => Array

Answer (score 0):

You are not implementing your equality operator correctly. It should be:

```
def == other
  other_name = case other
    when Role then other.name
    when String, Symbol then other.to_s
  end
  name == other_name
end
```

Comment: That was just a typo in the question (updated accordingly). As I said, checking for equality normally works, except in `include?`, where it is not even used.

Comment: I tried your code in my models, correcting the equality operator and include? works just fine...

Comment: I just started a new project just to double-check. It does still not work for me though. I updated to the newest rails version 3.2.12, still the same. Very odd... Are you sure, you tried it within a has_many relation and not just on an arbitrary array? e.g. `[Role.create(name: 'test'), Role.create(name: 'test_2')].include? 'test'` will work as expected but `user.roles.include? 'test'` will not.

Comment: I tried on my models, on an one-to-many relationship. `include?` worked for objects of the same model, strings and symbols as well... You should debug to see if your == operator method is being called when executing `include?`